# Logging the Behavior of a Binary?

Tags: debugging, logging, executable, instrumentation, instructions

I want to figure out which instructions are executed *differently* when a command-line flag is passed to a program on Windows, of which I have the compiled (and optimized) binary, with no debug symbols or anything of the sort. I know the difference will not be more than a handful of instructions.

How would I go about figuring this out? Are there any techniques for logging exactly which instructions a program executes over a certain period of time?
(Note that this does *not* involve any system calls, just a flag being set in a loop because of the command-line flag.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMD's CodeAnalyst to do this, using the instruction based profiling method. It also has an API you can all within you app to trigger events so you can monitor specific regions. You can also use a disassembler, as from what I understand, your using the word 'instruction' to mean both high level code operations and low level machine code(who execution cannot change, only the emitted code from the compiler can change the execution of high level operations).

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a really awesome tool. However, it often doesn't catch something, because most instructions don't even get sampled. Any ideas on how to fix that (if it's possible)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: then you can try one of the other sampling methods, such as time based. (there should be a sample tutorial with it).